# If i have to retrieve both list key and list value from checkboxlist

Tags: struts2

i dont know if its a dumb question but if it is am sorry (but my requirement is that way)
in my JSP am using struts2 tag of checkboxlist now

i want to fetch both listkey and listvalues into my action is their any way to do this ?

Comment: It's a checkbox-only the value is sent, that's how HTML checkboxes work.

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe there is other way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the key will be send directly in the action class by providing getter setter to the checkbox list name attribute and if u want the key then try using jquery .get the key by giving id to the checkbox and retrive it using the jquery syntax

```
$("#urid").val().
```

and set it in a

```
<s:hidden id="" name="" value=""/>.
```

Just provided the idea a bit of googling will get u to the solution enjoy.